# Composite Higgs $SO(5)\to SO(4)$ model: how is $H$ a composite particle?

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

I am reading [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01961) on CH models by Wulzer and Panico. In Section 2.2.2, they write a minimal model of $SO(5)$ breaking into $SO(4)$, triggering electroweak symmetry breaking (EWSB) with a composite Higgs.

However, I don't see how the Higgs defined as
$$H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\binom{\Pi_2+i\Pi_1}{\Pi_4-i\Pi_3}$$
would correspond to a composite particle and not to some kind of elementary particle.

Comment: You are perfectly and unequivocally happy with the previous section and the "resonance" imagery?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I understand that redefining the triplet as a perturbation of the vacuum introduces a massive particle which we can call a resonance, in analogy with QCD. However I don't understand how this is related to the compositeness of $H$, so not so perfectly happy

Comment: So maybe you should back up and ask your question about that. Moving on to SO(5)/SO(4) looks like overkill/over-reach... My sense is you could take time out and learn about the real σ of chiral symmetry breaking of QCD, the archetype of all this...

Comment: @CosmasZachos my question is perhaps simpler (and it involves this SO(5) model as well as the abelian one): how is this a model for a composite Higgs and not for some particular type of elementary Higgs? I know about chiral symmetry breaking but I don't think it can answer my question

Comment: The easiest way is to contrast all expressions, (2.2.8), (2.2.16), (2.2.33) with their SM limit, i.e. $\xi=0$. which means elementary: there *is no* compositeness and vacuum misalignment, etc... in that limit, as the Higgs field is all elementary, not Goldstone bosons of a two-step SSB as in the compositeness scale. Don't waste your time with sec 2.2.3, which simply expands the group theory of section 2.2.1, the abelian Higgs model. Review your SM elementary prototype for it, and then contrast the extra couplings in the composite!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ok, thank you